# Gremlin ReadOnly Transactional support

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am trying to configure a transaction for a Gremlin client that will not allow any mutating queries (Read-only).

I am aware that this is possible in JanusGraph or Titan with their API (with buildTransaction() as readOnly()), however for TinkerPop or Neptune I have not found anything similar.

I am using a java script based client (sessioned):

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.open();
Client client = cluster.connect('SessionID');
String mutatingQuery = "g.addV('Test')";
client.submit("g.tx().open()");
client.submit(mutatingQuery); // This should fail.
client.submit("g.tx().commit()");
```

I know you can restrict these types of queries from server side. But is this also possible from client side? I am also not sure if this is the correct approach to this problem.

Edit:
I am communicating remotely with Gremlin Server over WebSocket, by submitting "scripts".
From Java, I am configuring the cluster as:

```
Cluster cluster = 
    Cluster.build().addContactPoint(url).port(port).create();
```

And then using the client to submit queries:

```
Client c= cluster.connect().init();
c.submit(query);
```

I know about the ReadOnlyStrategy that a Graph supports. But I have not found a way to enable it through the above approach, only from server configuration script. Is there a another way to restrict the submitted "query"?

My server is configured with this default groovy script:

```
globals << [g : graph.traversal()] // Could have used readOnly strategy here.
```

And my client is sending queries like this:

```
c.submit("g.addV('test')"); // this should fail
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does any of the below suggestions work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kathrik, I have added comments in the bellow answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual transaction logic using `.tx()` is not currently supported in Neptune.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html -> Transactions

And as Kelvin mentioned in his answer, you can always make your application talk to the reader endpoint of the cluster, which lets you do only read-only operations. You can get the reader endpoint, by viewing the cluster details from console, or obtain the endpoint programmatically using the Neptune SDK.

```
aws neptune describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier \
    neptunedbcluster-t0wz5xpqmiuc --region us-east-1 --output table

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                      DescribeDBClusters                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                                         DBClusters                                                          ||
|+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  AllocatedStorage                 |  1                                                                                      ||
||  BackupRetentionPeriod            |  1                                                                                      ||
||  ClusterCreateTime                |  2018-10-16T04:17:23.384Z                                                               ||
||  DBClusterArn                     |  arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123123123123:cluster:neptunedbcluster-t0wz5xpqmiuc               ||
||  DBClusterIdentifier              |  neptunedbcluster-t0wz5xpqmiuc                                                          ||
||  DBClusterParameterGroup          |  neptunedbclusterparametergr-q6eekezcpd04                                               ||
||  DBSubnetGroup                    |  neptunedbsubnetgroup-dmcliosqke8b                                                      ||
||  DbClusterResourceId              |  cluster-AEFFOL3WFA7W5H7WL4QWEQWEQWE                                                     ||
||  EarliestRestorableTime           |  2018-10-21T07:04:17.379Z                                                               ||
||  Endpoint                         |  neptunedbcluster-t0wz5xpqmiuc.cluster-qweqweqwe.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com     ||
||  Engine                           |  neptune                                                                                ||
||  EngineVersion                    |  1.0.1.0                                                                                ||
||  HostedZoneId                     |  ZUFXD4SLT2LS7                                                                          ||
||  IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled |  False                                                                                  ||
||  LatestRestorableTime             |  2018-10-22T17:16:44.233Z                                                               ||
||  MasterUsername                   |  admin                                                                                  ||
||  MultiAZ                          |  False                                                                                  ||
||  Port                             |  8182                                                                                   ||
||  PreferredBackupWindow            |  06:52-07:22                                                                            ||
||  PreferredMaintenanceWindow       |  mon:09:33-mon:10:03                                                                    ||
||  ReaderEndpoint                   |  neptunedbcluster-t0wz5xpqmiuc.cluster-ro-qweqweqwe.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com  ||
||  Status                           |  available                                                                              ||
||  StorageEncrypted                 |  False                                                                                  ||
|+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
|||                                                      AssociatedRoles                                                      |||
||+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  RoleArn |  arn:aws:iam::393993383537:role/RDS-2-Neptune-Demo-NeptuneBa-NeptuneLoadFromS3Role-1NKBKFMRK6L1G               |||
|||  Status  |  ACTIVE                                                                                                        |||
||+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||                                                     AvailabilityZones                                                     |||
||+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  us-east-1b                                                                                                               |||
|||  us-east-1c                                                                                                               |||
|||  us-east-1a                                                                                                               |||
||+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||                                                     DBClusterMembers                                                      |||
||+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  DBClusterParameterGroupStatus                             |  in-sync                                                     |||
|||  DBInstanceIdentifier                                      |  neptunedbinstance-owqd0npl6ar4                              |||
|||  IsClusterWriter                                           |  True                                                        |||
|||  PromotionTier                                             |  1                                                           |||
||+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||                                                     VpcSecurityGroups                                                     |||
||+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||              Status               |                                  VpcSecurityGroupId                                   |||
||+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
|||  active                           |  sg-01ab9e609e122c01b                                                                 |||
|||  active                           |  sg-0723b9b248cbe20a3                                                                 |||
||+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+||
```

Note that the reader endpoint is available as `ReaderEndpoint` in the result.

UPDATE:
If you have only one instance in your cluster, then both reader and writer endpoints point to the same instance. If you want a truly read-only endpoint, you should create a multi instance cluster, in which case the reader endpoint does a DNS round robin between the readers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am looking for a way to enforce a read-only style of querying the database using the above approach. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: See updated answer and let me know if that suits your usecase.

Comment: The ReaderEndpoint server is really amazing. But when I used it, I could actually run addV queries.  I got my output like that: 
aws neptune describe-db-clusters --query 'DBClusters[?Engine==neptune].[ReaderEndpoint]' --output text

Comment: @ThanosG Did you try that on a cluster with just one instance, or was that a multi-instance cluster? RO endpoints for Single instance clusters would point to the writer itself. RO endpoints point excludes the writer only when there are multiple instances in the cluster.

Comment: That must be it. I have only one. So the solution to that, would be to create one more so the RO points to it?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways using Neptune that you can enforce read-only style semantics for a given use case. One would be to use a TinkerPop ReadOnly Strategy. The other would be to only allow the user/application access to the read endpoint of the cluster and not the writer endpoint..

Could you say a bit more about the specific use case you have?

UPDATED: Here is an example of creating a ReadOnlyStrategy using Java from a client application:

```
// Experiment with the ReadOnlyStrategy
    g2 = g.withStrategies(ReadOnlyStrategy.instance());
    try
    {
      g2.addV("shouldfail").iterate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Unable to add vertex as expected");
    }
```

Cheers,
Kelvin

Comment: Thanks Kevin, for your response. Could you please tell me more on how can I restrict user/application access to the read endpoint through a remote approach? I have also updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example of creating a ReadOnlyStrategy from Java from the client application. Rather than using the client.submit() approach you can use the remote connection approach which will send your query using Gremlin byte code to the server.

Comment: Thank for your answer. However I currently cannot use the above method, since my queries are "unknown" at this time. So my only way is to use client.submit("unknown_query").

Comment: Wow! Is this `ReadOnlyStrategy` possibile with `gremlin` nodejs library?

Comment: Should be yes. It's one of the standard Gremlin strategies.